# jQuery: How to get an id, manipulate it to select another id?

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following:

```
<input type="radio" class="trigger" id="some-id" />
<div id="some-id-target">…</div>
<input type="radio" class="trigger" id="12345" />
<div id="12345-target">…</div>
```

How do I write a general function to target the div from the input field id?

This is what I am kind of thinking but not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function toggleDiv() {
        var triggerBox = $(this).attr('id'),
            $targetBox = '$("#' + triggerBox + '-target")';
        $targetBox.toggle();
    }

    $('.trigger').on('change',toggleDiv);
});
```

Hope this is clear and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have extra quotes when you are setting $targetBox:

```
$targetBox = $('#' + triggerBox + '-target');
```

should work